# Critical point of $f(x,y) = x^{3} -3xy^{2}, x,y \in \Bbb{ R}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y) = x^{3} -3xy^{2}, x,y \in \Bbb{R}$. Then what can you conclude about its critical point $(0,0) ?$

For this function $f_{xx} f_{yy} - f_{xy}^{2} = 0$ at $(0,0)$ 
So the test gives no result.

The function can be written as $x(x^{2} - 3y^{2}) = x(x- √3 y)(x+√3 y)$

Now how do we know the nature of function near $(0,0) $ ?

Comment: The factorization tells you what you need to know about the sign of $f$, doesn't it?

Comment: See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle

Comment: For Hessian it should be $f_{xy}^2$

Comment: @dmtri thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(x,y)=x(x^2-3y^2)$. So, if $x>0$ and $y^2<\frac13x^2$, $f(x,y)>0$. And if $x>0$ and $y^2>\frac13x^2$, $f(x,y)<0$. Therefore, $(0,0)$ is a saddle point of $f$.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but was not sure. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Take the path $y=x$. Then you have that

$$g(x)=f(x,x)=x(x^2-3x^2)=-2x^3$$

As function of one variable $g$ does not have at $x=0$ any local maximum or local minimum since $g(x)>0$ if $x<0$ while $g(x)<0$ if $x>0$. This is enough to say that also $f$ does not have at $(0,0)$ any local maximum or local minimum, otherwise $g$ does. Therefore $(0,0)$ is a saddle point for $f$.